# Two digits selected from $1$ to $9$ and the sum is odd , what is the probability that one of the digits is $2$

Tags: probability

The answer given in the book is $1/4$ but i don't understand how that can be so. What i understand from the question is this based on conditional probability. i have to find :

P(one number being $2$ , GIVEN sum of two numbers is odd) = P(2 $\cap$ odd sum)$\div$ P(odd sum)

but i'm not sure how to do/calculate this. Any help? Also , do correct me if my understanding is wrong.

edit : Repeats are not allowed in selection. Forgot to add this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the sum is odd, one number is odd and the other is even. Thus there are $2\times 5\times 4 = 40$ choices for selecting a pair of number whose sum is odd. Of these pairs, there are $2\times 5 = 10$ pairs with one of the numbers is $2$. Thus the answer is $\dfrac{10}{40} = \dfrac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Regarding $2*5*4$ part , is it like : (selecting odd followed by even) + (selecting even followed by odd) ? both being $5*4$ ?

Comment: The first one since $(1,6)$ and $(6,1)$ are counted as different choices.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion don't go to formulas try to work it out

Consider the ordered pairs $(1,2),(1,4),(1,6),(1,8)$ when $1^{st}$ element of ordered pair is taken as$1$

Consider the ordered pairs $(2,1),(2,3),(2,5),(2,7),(2,9)$ when $1^{st}$ element of ordered pair is taken as$2$

going on in this way see that when we have the $1^{st}$ element of the ordered pair odd we get $4$ elements  and when even we get $5$ elements.Since from $1$ to $9$ we have  $5$ odd and $4$ even elements  we get number of elemnts to be $5\times +4\times 5=40 $  elements.total number of possible outcomes =40
No. of elements having an element 2 is 5+5=10 since each when the 1st lement of the ordered pair is odd we can have 2as the other element in the pair otherwise not.And another 5 as I have explicitly written down viz.  $(2,1),(2,3),(2,5),(2,7),(2,9)$
Favourable oucomes =10

So prob.=$10/40=1/4$

Comment: Nice explanation. But can u say why my formula based logic wasn't working ? or if it was.. how can i solve it that way ? i say this because maybe for bigger problems , i might not be able to count explicitly like this...

Comment: Take $A$=one of the digits is odd and $B$=sum is odd  $P(A|B)=P(A\cap B)/(P(B)) $ On finding that I get $P(A\cap B)=10;(P(B))=40$ I am not in touch with it for long.See if this suits you